# Recommendations on accessing current user data in WordPress

Tags: globals

While reading the [following WordPress Codex page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Global_Variables) on Global variable usage, there is a bold line that states

**

> Accessing other globals besides the ones listed below is not
>   recommended.

**
My question is in concern to using the global variable `$current_user`.  Is it not recommended to use something like this in my functions.php file?

```
if ($current_user->display_name){
  echo '<p>welcome ' . $current_user->display_name . '</p>';
}
```

...or are there other alternative methods I should start building habits on without depending on WordPress global variables not mentioned on that Codex page?

I know what I am asking for probably doesn't have a black and white answer, but I would like to get the opinion from some of you guys how have been coding in wordpress for a while.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`wp_get_current_user()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_current_user/) instead of using the `$current_user` global.

```
$my_current_user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( $my_current_user->display_name ) {
    echo '<p>Welcome ' . $my_current_user->display_name . '</p>';
}
```

Note that I used `$my_current_user` instead of `$current_user` as a variable name, because you can run into trouble if you use the global variable's name.